# How to dynamically increase textbox height based on text height and start with total screen 30%

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, inputbox

I am trying to create textbox like
Empty textbox start with 30% of the total screen height.
And if data is there in textbox and then create height of the textbox based on data height.
And also increase height of the textbox dynamic while typing text overflow the width.

[image: Result:]

what is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this is what you're looking for:

```js
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
```

```css
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    min-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init();">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use textarea property

```css
textarea{

min-width:30%;
max-width:100%;

}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple HTML/CSS example using a [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) `div`.

```css
body {
background-color: black;
}

div {
min-height: 30vh;
/* adjust width to your preference */
width: 30%;
background-color: #ffffff;
}


/* code below is for placeholder text, you can remove if not required */
[contenteditable][placeholder]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  color: gray;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div placeholder="Keep typing to expand..." contenteditable></div>
```